# ¿Cómo mostrar números legibles en kb, M, GB, etc, usando sadf de sysstat Linux?

Tags: linux, sysstat, sar

**CONTEXTO.** Rhel 8.6, sysstat 11.7.3

**PROBLEMA.**
Si ejecuto `sadf /var/log/sa/sa30 -- -b`, me devuelve lo siguiente. Como se ve, no se especifica si los números vienen en kb, en M, en GB, etc.

```
2022-08-31 04:50:01 UTC -       tps     3.40
2022-08-31 04:50:01 UTC -       rtps    0.05
2022-08-31 04:50:01 UTC -       wtps    3.35
2022-08-31 04:50:01 UTC -       bread/s 9.97
2022-08-31 04:50:01 UTC -       bwrtn/s 183.75
```

Según la documentación de [sar](http://man.he.net/man1/sar), existe un flag llamado `--human` que permite convertir los números a kb, M, GB, etc. Y según la documentación de [sadf](http://man.he.net/man1/sadf), podemos usar los flags de sar poniendo dos guiones (--) y luego los flags de sar. El problema es que si uso el flag `--human` nunca se genera el reporte, porque según sadf está mal formado mi comando.

Sin éxito, he intentado usar `--human` como sigue:

1. sadf /var/log/sa/sa30 -- --human
2. sadf /var/log/sa/sa30 --human
3. sadf /var/log/sa/sa30 -- human
4. sadf /var/log/sa/sa30 -- '--human'
5. sadf /var/log/sa/sa30 -- "--human"

Cualquier ayuda será apreciada.

Answer (score 0):

Pareciera que `--human` es una opción.... por convención, se colocan *antes* que los argumentos. Esto debería funcionar:

```
sadf --human /var/log/sa/sa30
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, @efshift0, pero no funciona En la documentación sadf, indica que los flags sar (como lo es --human), deben ir al final.